# How can I get multiple collision contacts of the same clones at the same time? Unity2D/Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want 2 things to instantiate on 2 different positions when 2 different collisions of the same clones happen.

But when they happen at the same exact time, only 1 of the collision gets called.

This code instantiates a fire on the position of their collision, but when there's 2 different collisions of the same clones happen at the same time in 2 different positions, the instantiator only instantiates on the position of one of the collisions, but not the other collisions.

This is on 2D by the way.

Let's say there's 4 rockets (They all have the same scripts and behaviours, since they're clones). The 1st one collides with the 2nd one, and the 3rd one collides with the 4th one AT THE SAME TIME WITH THE 1ST AND 2ND ONE. This should create 2 collision points. But it only instantiates on one of the collision points.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour {

//Variables
bool exploded;
bool explosion;
Vector3 rocketPoint;

//The tag of this object is "rocket"

void Start ()

{
exploded = true;
explosion = false;
}

void Update ()

{

if(explosion && exploded)

{
InvokeRepeating("fire",0,60);
exploded = false;
explosion = false;
}

}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)

{
if (col.gameObject.CompareTag ("rocket"))
{
//Gets the position of the collision with the other rockets.
ContactPoint2D contact = col.contacts[0];
rocketPoint = contact.point;

explosion = true;

//Calls function that destroys the rocket after 0.01 seconds after colliding
InvokeRepeating("destroyThis",0.01f,0.01f);
}
}

//The "Instantiator"
void fire()

{
Instantiate(Resources.Load("Fire"), rocketPoint, Quaternion.identity);
exploded = true;
}

//Destroys the rocket after 0.01 seconds after colliding.
void destroyThis()

{
Destroy (gameObject);
}

}
```